# How to insert event into a private Google Calendar with PHP?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to add new events into my **private Google Calendar**, but I get **(403) Forbidden** message. I've searched the internet but I found no answer to my issue.

My **scope** is set to read/write, and the credentials should be ok, because I can read out all of my events so the connection works fine.

Here's the code:

```
$service_account = $this->service_account;
$json_key = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->json_url));
$scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
$application_name = 'Calendar';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName($application_name);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($service_account, array($scopes), $json_key->private_key);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);       
}

$google_service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);


$calendar_ids = $this->calendar_ids;
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();


$event->setSummary($service);
$event->setDescription($user);
$event->setLocation($location);
$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime($this->sqlDateToGcalDate($start_date));
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime($this->sqlDateToGcalDate($end_date));
$event->setEnd($end);

$google_service->events->insert($calendar_ids[$steed], $event);
$google_service->events->insert($calendar_ids[$location], $event);
```

Comment: Your service account needs to be a writer in the ACL list of the calendar into which you are adding the events. You can fix this for example by going to the web UI and adding the service account email to the sharing list of the calendar. Btw, if this is a calendar owned by a domain, the setup is more complicated and you will need to delegate domain-wide authority to the service account.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem, thanks for the answer. :)